# Remove/reduce overlapping edges with Cytoscape. (Planar Graph)

Tags: cytoscape.js

I am trying to achieve the below:

[image]

Instead it looks like this:

[image]

I am using the [cose-bilkent](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-cose-bilkent) layout as per an example [here:](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-cose-bilkent/issues/7)

are there any other js libraries or correct ways to implement what I want?

Comment: Is it possible, that another layout may resolve this issue? The creator of cytoscape.js pointed this out already, when some people requested the no overlap feature for their graphs. Sometimes the graph looks bad, because the layout doesn't have the right fit, so try out other ones like [klay](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-klay)